# How to configure Jetty 8 to use syslog

Tags: ubuntu, jetty, syslog

Running on Ubuntu I want Jetty 8 to write to syslog instead of the logs folder. In my Java I just want to use getLogger.info(messaeg)...

I can see my app logs in the Jetty logs at `$JETTY_HOME/logs`, but I want all Jetty messages to be written to syslog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to use slf4j + logback as described here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Sifting_Logs_with_Logback

Then you can configure logback to write to a syslog appender like this one:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender

Should be pretty straight forward using these documentations. If you still have any questions, ask right away.